# how to manage the onsen-ui framework with separate file using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

How can i manage the sliding-menu and tab-bar in every page.. and how can i separate the all file just like

```
www
 ->js
 ->css
 ->template
    ->list-view.html
    ->Show-data
  index.html
```

How can i manage this in onsen ui

Thanx in advance

Comment: inside js folder create one more folder called Angular and apply the same for css..for managing sliding menu you should write a directive and do DOM manipulation over there

Comment: please sir can you explain in sample code i have try this but i can't solve it

Comment: can you put sample code that you tried.

Comment: @pankajparkar Can you help me for this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28164918/how-can-i-send-the-data-from-php-to-angularjs-show-detail